# charmap codec cant encode characters in position xx - xx

Tags: python, csv, unicode

I am trying to use unicodecsv python library in python 2.7.x

```
import codecs
import unicodecsv

def read(self, path):
    with codecs.open(path, "rb", encoding = "utf-8") as f:
        r = unicodecsv.reader(f, encoding = 'utf-8')    
        row = r.next()
        print row


read("unicode.csv")
```

**Error:**
charmap codec cant encode characters in position xx - xx

I have manually converted my csv file to utf-8 using txt editors so i am sure the input file is fine

Comment: Do you have file actually in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry yes i do. I use sublime text to encode in utf-8 before saving it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see few problems with your code:

```
def read(self, path):
```

You using `self` no within `class`

after opening file with `codecs.open`you can use standard python `csv` reader.

With some modifications:

```
f = "/home/dzagorulkin/workspace/zont/file.txt"

import codecs
#import unicodecsv

def read(path):
    with codecs.open(path, "rb", encoding = "utf-8") as f:            
        for line in f:
            print line
read(f)
```

i used none ASCII file and output:

> Меня Дима зовут! Меня Дима зовут!